# Reading XML file in ASP.NET Website - Operating Efficiency

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net

Project type: ASP.NET Website

Currently we are employing a set of lookup data stored as an XML file inside the project to fill data on a certain ASPX page.

We're looking at changing this approach to the one below citing efficiency:

Store the XML file values in Database. Fetch the values from Database on application start (Global.asax). Store in an in-memory object like LIST or HASHTABLE and Use this further.

Is this a valid approach? Is there something that could be done better?

If you need any more details, please leave a comment below. I'll be happy to share.

Answer (score 0):

If you need read only access, you can declare a static variable in the global.asax and use the Application_Start event.

Comment: In a Web model, while there are many requests coming in for this application, how good is this approach? Are there any downsides?

Comment: the event Application_Start is triggered only when you start the web application. I assume this is shared data which is global to all users sessions. if you need read/write this approach is no good idea, i would consider Redis as fast data store.

Comment: There is only a one-way (Only reading, no read-write) Sort of a lookup data.

Comment: i used it for such scenarios without problems.

Comment: Thanks Snoopy. Let me test this suggestion.